# "Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11" в Ajax запросах

Tags: javascript, ajax

При ajax запросах у меня выскакивает ошибка. Интересно то, что скрипт выполняется визуально без ошибок, а Google Chrome в Инструментах разработчика выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

```
function get_phrase_for_valid(){
var request = getXmlHttp(); 

 request.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(request.status == 200  && request.readyState == 4) {//<=здесь эта ошибка
     if(request.responseText!=''){ 
        document.getElementById('PraseInput').style.display= 'block';
        }
        else{
        document.getElementById('PraseInput').style.display= 'none';
        }
    }
}
 request.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
 request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 request.send("&act=get_phrase_fv");        
}
```

Comment: Косяк где-то при работе с DOMом. Возможно, неправильно работает какой-то из плагинов. В других браузерах работает нормально?

Comment: плагинов нет. Чистый javascript

Comment: Больше кода пожалуйста, по тому что вы запостили понять что либо практически невозможно

Comment: Вот этот кусок кода.
Ошибка - первая строка.
Где ошибка, я отметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу прощения, поправил в предыдущем ответе и тут не увидел (странно что никто не увидел до этого...)

Вообщем суть в следующем - когда используется асинхронный ajax запрос, поле 'status' буде существовать исключительно при 'readyState == 4' независимо от того какой именно ответ прийдет.

Т.е. если написать так:

```
request.status == 200  && request.readyState == 4
```

Мы сначала проверяем status ответа (которые не факт что пришел), но нам сначала надо проверить пришел ли он и только потом проверять его статус.

Таким образом необходимо просто поменять местами

```
request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200
```

Теперь в теле условия мы сначало проверяем пришел ли ответ от сервера( в том числе статус ) и только когда он уже пришел - проверяем и его. Еще раз прошу прощения за мою невнимательность в предыдущем ответе.

Comment: Ну и вместо "&act=get_phrase_fv" шлите "act=get_phrase_fv", но это к этой ошибке не относиться